# jQuery ui dialog disappears on page refresh?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, refresh, reload

I've got a basic dialog which should be always shown until the user clicks a button. The problem is that after I refresh the page manually it disappears, but if I refresh it again it reappears. How should I fix that so that it wouldn't disappear after the 1st refresh?

Sample:

```
   <?php
    $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT tut FROM users WHERE username='$session_username'");
    while ($tutno = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
        $tut = $tutno["tut"];
    }
    if ($tut == 0)
    {
    ?>

 <html><body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sciencewar.hostme.lt/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sciencewar.hostme.lt/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#tut" ).dialog(
            {
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false
            });
        });
        </script>

    <div id="tut" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>Example.</p>
    </div>
    </body></html>
    <?

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample, or a link to the page where you're seeing the problem?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some source code?

Comment: I've looked and found out that this only happens on opera (v11.01). Anyone knows the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Since your javascript is correct I can only assume that the problem is in

```
if($tut == 0)
```

line. Could you verify if your javascript is rendered at all on the page?

You can also remove the `if` statement and check if the dialog appears at all times.

Comment: It's rendered and the dialog appears with or without the if but no matter in which way after refresh it disappears. I don't think that the code has any problems. Maybe I need to add something to keep the dialog after the refresh? I'm quite new at codding so don't know that much.